# Is it possible to access the FTP deployment site logs for my account

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are needing to see the FTP transfer logs for one of our azure web sites.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to access the FTP deployment site logs for my account

I can't find any way to do it. Normally in IIS, we can install FTP Extensibility and enable the FTP transfer log through FTP Logging button.

[image]

After [remote administration of Windows Azure Websites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/) using IIS Manager, I can't find the FTP Logging button.  We can only find some buttons as following.

[image]

Comment: Hi amor,
Thanks for the info. I'm sorry but maybe I could have been a little more clear. What I am seeking is the file transfer logs for the site's deployment slot when you have ftp selected as the method to use to deploy new code to the site. These ftp deployment services are under MS control, so what I'm hoping is that if someone knows how these logs if available, can be access by the site admin...

Comment: I also can't find any way to access the FTP ftransfer log. Please send a feature request on following site. http://feedback.azure.com

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in **Azure App Service**, the **FTP** logs are not exposed to the end users. The access is restricted to **Microsoft**.

You may want to raise a feedback here for the **Azure app services** team: [Azure Web Apps User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps)

Comment: Thanks, yep I reached out and they were able to get me the relevant logs.

Comment: For those who are interested in this feature seeing the light of day, please head to this particular [Azure Web Apps UserVoice page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/19827436-a-method-to-allow-folks-to-access-the-ftp-transfer) and upvote it.